# Sampling from a point pattern

Tags: numpy

I have a 3D point distribution in a numpy array formed of 1,000,000 points, lets call it `points`. I would like to take a 10% uniform sample so that the points are evenly distributed (e.g. every 10th point)

I think this is what I'm looking for but this generates data, how do I sample existing data?

```
numpy.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=1.0, size=None)
```

Comment: You could share an example of your data with desired output.

Answer (score 1):

In case I understood the problem right you would just need to do this:

```
points[::10]
```

to get every 10th element of `points`.

If that is not what you wanted, please clarify.

Comment: the OP should clarify, still I think that he means  3D points i.e `Nx3` size matrix **(x,y,z)**, not 3D matrix.

Comment: Sorry, did a mistake with the commas there, this is what I meant. But yeah, clarification would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

simple indexing will do it:

```py
# data
x = numpy.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=1.0, size=(300,3))

#sampled result
sample_step = 10
y = x[:-1:sample_step]
```